# Change max length of signature field to more than 255 characters

Tags: 7, users, database

How can I change the max length of the drupal 7 signature field to more than 255 characters? I've already changed the sql data type from 255 to varchar(900), yet drupal still shows the error, as soon as a user wants to update his signature to more than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

In a mysql database varchar can only store 255 characters.

Comment: Nope. It can store more. I've changed it to 900 and manually entered a siganture longer than 255 Characters into the MySQL signature field of a certain user - worked without a problem. Also, changing the data type from varchar to another didn't help either, it was still limited to 255 in Drupal.

Comment: WOW I feel old.  You are right.
"Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used."

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the case but you can look around the module(code) and do this but you are on your own ,, because its dangerous

[enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_field_settings)

> This module allows you to change (uneditable) settings for fields.
>
> READ WITH CAUTION: Please don't use this module unless you know what
>   the hell is this module does which I'm NOT sure about 100% ,, so I'd
>   recommend using it in stage/dev/local environment until you are sure
>   about it